# Could i shortin this code?

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I have this code and i am so bad in PHP, could someone show me how to optimize this? i think the code could be shorter somehow?

I tried to put all the echo's in one line somehow but no luck ...

```
<?php
$metakey = 'evcal_srow';
$zeit = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
 if ($zeit) {
 foreach ($zeit as $evcal_srow) {
 echo "<div class='datum'>";
 echo gmdate("d.m.Y", $evcal_srow);
 echo "</div>";
 echo "<div class='uhrzeit'>";
 echo gmdate("H:i", $evcal_srow);
 echo "</div>";
 }
 }
?>
```

thx!

Comment: I think it looks quite alright, although you should consider seperating your logic (getting stuff from the database) from your view (echo'ing it) more.

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is no point in preparing a query if you are going to inject the variable directly.

Comment: I think [`printf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) is cleaner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concentrate strings and only call one `echo`, as well as removing extra spaces. Less readable, but fewer lines.

```
<?php
$metakey = 'evcal_srow';
$zeit = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
 if ($zeit) {
 foreach ($zeit as $evcal_srow) {
 echo "<div class='datum'>";
 echo gmdate("d.m.Y", $evcal_srow);
 echo "</div>";
 echo "<div class='uhrzeit'>";
 echo gmdate("H:i", $evcal_srow);
 echo "</div>";
 }
 }
?>
```

becomes

```
<?php $metakey='evcal_srow'; $zeit=$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey));
if($zeit){foreach($zeit as $evcal_srow){
    echo "<div class='datum'>".gmdate("d.m.Y", $evcal_srow)."</div><div class='uhrzeit'>".gmdate("H:i", $evcal_srow)."</div>";
}} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the echo's by just stepping out of PHP, but this is personal preference.

```
<?php
$metakey = 'evcal_srow';
$zeit = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
 if ($zeit) {
    foreach ($zeit as $evcal_srow) { ?>

       <div class='datum'> <?php echo gmdate("d.m.Y", $evcal_srow); ?> </div>
       <div class='uhrzeit'><?php echo gmdate("H:i", $evcal_srow); ?> </div>

     <? }
 }
?>
```

Alternatively you can look into MVC and how to load a seperate 'view' template which has the responsibility of displaying your information. This way you can seperate your logic from the view.

Comment: Or even shorten further by changing `<?php echo` to `<?=`

Comment: Personally i'm a fan of short_tags as well, but not everyone is. Also it requires you to have it enabled in your PHP.ini (i think it is by default, but many disable it), so i wanted to play on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the echo statements like this. With the . you just add each after the other

```
<?php
$metakey = 'evcal_srow';
$zeit = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta    WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
if ($zeit) {
  foreach ($zeit as $evcal_srow) {
    echo "<div class='datum'>".gmdate("d.m.Y", $evcal_srow)."</div><div class='uhrzeit'>".gmdate("H:i", $evcal_srow);."</div>";
   }
}
?>
```